# file_get_contents on other port

Tags: php, rest, file-get-contents

I must contact services rest on different ports by 80, but the function file_get_contents () returns an error: failed to open stream: Connection refused

```
$url = "http://nexusdigital.agency:81/API/....";

$result = file_get_contents($url, false);
```

How can I configure the reading on other ports?

Comment: This should do just fine, if the URL `nexusdigital.agency:81` actually exists and is physically reachable from your location.

Comment: Read the error. `Connection refused`. Your server cannot connect to the other server on port `81`. This could be that the remote server isn't letting you, or that there's a firewall on your own server (or in rare cases, your ISP) blocking you from making outgoing calls on port `81`. Try to telnet from your server's console and see if you get any other output.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.
The service exists and is accessible, in fact, the browser reads the contents

You can try clicking this address
http://nexusdigital.agency:81/API/MENEC/campagne-sms-uscita.php?serial=H58GJDD9H

but if you enter this address into the function fails

Comment: @NexusDigital Where are you running this code? From the same computer that you're using the browser on? Do you have a firewall blocking php from accessing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CURL :

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://nexusdigital.agency/API/....'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 81); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 81); 
$result = curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

Comment: I tried this code but it does not work.
I think that my hosting has closed these outgoing ports.

Comment: The question was how to set port for file_get_contents(). Your reply does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it doesn't work for you (whatever the reason) you can try using CURL http://php.net/curl

```
<?php
$tuCurl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nexusdigital.agency/API/...."); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT , 81); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // 5 seconds timeout

$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl); 
curl_close($tuCurl);
```