# file_get_contents refused connection centos7

Tags: php, linux, mpdf

i made for a client one application which is sending orders to database and after this from a cms can print or download these orders as PDF and save in a folder, the problem is on my host paid host is working but when i move entire app on linux machine and i start to place orders i am getting this:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://xxxxxxxx.com:84/comanda-detalii.php?id=48): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/html/comenzi.php on line 46

Line 46 looks like this:

```
$url =  (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$message = "Catre xxxxxx Print SRL</br>Prin prezenta comanda ferma va rugam sa ne tipariti urmatoarea publicatie :</br>";
$message .= file_get_contents($url.'/comanda-detalii.php?id='.(int)$orderId);
$title = "Comanda ferma";
$pdf = buildPdf($message,"Detalii comanda.pdf");
sendEmail($message,$to,$title,["continut"=>$pdf,"nume"=>"Detalii comanda.pdf"]);
file_put_contents("arhiva/Comanda ".$orderId.".pdf",$pdf);
header('Location: '.$currentpath);
```

What i am doing on this file? When user place an order i use MPDF to create this order as PDF and send it as attachements on email, save in folder.

Comment: It would seem that file_get_contents can't access that URL.  Can you access that URL in your browser?  Is port 48 open on the server?

Comment: @FoulFoot that would be port 84 :)

Comment: Er, right!  Dyslexia.

Comment: my url is like this transfer.xxxxx.com:84, i think it`s open right?

Comment: Port 84 has to be open on the server you are trying to connect to as well as the server you are on. Since you say it works from a different server, I imagine you were connecting to the same server from there. So, my guess is that you need to open port 84 on the Linux machine. Maybe a firewall config or a router config?

Comment: And, as @FoulFoot asked, if you put that URL (including the :84 port) in your browser on that Linux box, does it work?

Comment: i put down firewall and still getting this error. I get this error when i use file_get_contents.

Comment: Yes is working @MER

Comment: were you connecting to port 84 like that when you ran it on the paid host?

Comment: I don`t understand what you mean, on paid host used apache and maria db for mysql with php 7.1, so basically on this linux i put the client to install on centos Linux server php 7.1 and maria db for mysql.

Comment: So, the server in the `$url` variable. Is that some other server somewhere or does that point to your Linux server?

Comment: this is my variable -> $url =  (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687851/file-get-contents-on-other-port .  Basically we're saying is that there's nothing wrong with file_get_contents -- it's simply that the server that this code is on cannot reach the server specified in the URL.  It is very probable that it's the port number that is the problem; web servers are almost always on port 80, and host providers will sometimes close non-standard ports.

Comment: I made it with curl and still not working i get the same error.

Comment: Then port 84 is not open on the server hosting comanda-detalii.php.  Whether that's something you can configure or not, I don't know.  If not, then your only solution is to work through port 80, which you will not have to specify in the URL (it's 80 by default).

Comment: The only other possibility is that *outbound* port 84 is blocked on the server hosting comenzi.php.  That would be pretty odd though; most firewalls I'm familiar with don't bother filtering outbound traffic.